# Not able to call functions defined in DLL using python cffi from JNA

Tags: java, python, jna, python-cffi

I have created a DLL from python file `plugin.py` (code is shown below) using `cffi`. I tried to call the `do_stuff()` function from Java using JNA, however I am getting errors like "function my_plugin.do_stuff() called, but initialization code failed.  Returning 0."  It is not calling the python function which is present in dll.

I have tried to call windows existing Kernel32.dll using JNA and that's working, so I am not sure what is the difference between the windows dll and my created DLL.

Code: plugin.py

```
import cffi
ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()
ffibuilder.embedding_api("""
    int do_stuff(int, int);
""")
ffibuilder.set_source("my_plugin", "")
ffibuilder.embedding_init_code("""
    from my_plugin import ffi

    @ffi.def_extern()
    def do_stuff(x, y):
        print("adding %d and %d" % (x, y))
        return x + y
""")
ffibuilder.compile(target="MyDllPlugin-1.5.*", verbose=True)
```

If we run with command `python plugin.py` after resolving `pip` and `cffi` dependency you will get `my_plugin.c` and `MyDllPlugin-1.5.dll` files in current directory.

Java code to call **MyDllPlugin-1.5.dll**

```
public class PythonToJavaDll {
    public interface NativeInterface extends Library {
        int do_stuff(int x, int y);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Native Library started");
        NativeInterface nativeExample = (NativeInterface)Native.loadLibrary("MyDllPlugin-1.5",NativeInterface.class);
        int value = nativeExample.do_stuff(3,4);
        System.out.println("String value:"+value);
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
Native Library started
function my_plugin.do_stuff() called, but initialization code failed.  
Returning 0.
String value:0
```

However when I run existing C:/windows/System32/kernel32.dll file then I am able to call methods of DLL.

```
public class BeepExampl {
    public interface Kernel32 extends Library {
        // FREQUENCY is expressed in hertz and ranges from 37 to 32767
        // DURATION is expressed in milliseconds
        public boolean Beep(int FREQUENCY, int DURATION);
        public void Sleep(int DURATION);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Native Library started");
        Kernel32 lib = Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
        System.out.println("Native Lib:" + lib);
        lib.Beep(698, 500);
        System.out.println("Sleep Started:" + new Date());
        lib.Sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Sleep End:" + new Date());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Native Library started
Native Lib:Proxy interface to Native Library <kernel32.dll@140715486085120>
Sleep Started:Fri Aug 14 21:16:48 IST 2020
Sleep End:Fri Aug 14 21:16:48 IST 2020
Native Lib:Proxy interface to Native Library <kernel32.dll@140715486085120>
```

Can anyone help to call Python DLL in Java using Java(JNA)?

Comment: It should print much more information when it fails to initialize.  I don't understand why it doesn't here.  You will have to use a debugger to single-step inside the CFFI module's initialization logic, starting at the C function ``_cffi_start_python``.

Comment: @ArminRigo: Yes, that's why not able to understand exactly what is it

Comment: @ArminRigo: because getting only this error" function my_plugin.do_stuff() called, but initialization code failed." but seems functions are not calling. Will try to debug now.

Comment: The problem does not appear to be in JNA, as those mappings look good. Is it a path/permission issue for whatever code starts python?

Comment: @DanielWiddis: I tried to set permissions using "icacls" command to file and directory on Windows 10, still getting same issue.

Comment: @DanielWiddis:
**C:\Windows\system32>icacls "C:\Windows\System32\EntryPoint2_Plugin_1.5.dll" /grant everyone:f**

processed file: C:\Windows\System32\EntryPoint2_Plugin_1.5.dll
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


**C:\Windows\system32>icacls "C:\WorkingPython\EntryPoint2_Plugin_1.5" /grant everyone:f**

processed file: C:\WorkingPython\EntryPoint2_Plugin_1.5
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

EntryPoint2_Plugin_1.5 - is my directory

Comment: Understood on the permissions, but how about the path, relative to wherever your Java program is running? I'm just guessing here, my expertise is in Java/JNA which you have right, and can't help much on the python/C/cffi stuff

Comment: Issue is resolve now. I am successfully able to call python function from Java using JNA.
Problem was:  _cffi_backend was not loading properly from CFFI, so was getting code initialization error. I have updated CFFI with 64bits Python 3.8.5 and ran the same code.Code worked like Charm.

Thanks @DanielWiddis

Comment: Now have another question regarding this connectivity will post as separate question.